# How to access child controls in a parent user control place holder?

Tags: gridview, user-controls, placeholder

I have a scenario where , I have user control file **abc.ascx** that has a dropdownlist, whose ListItems values are also usercontrol files **a.ascx**,**b.ascx**,**c.ascx**.
When *b.ascx* is selected in the dropdownlist present in *abc.ascx* , a GridView is populated within *b.ascx* and is displayed in a place-holder on *abc.ascx*
Is it possible to access the populated gridview of *b.ascx* in *abc.ascx* through the place holder ? If so, how ?

Answer (score 0):

I tried and was able to access the b.ascx gridview in abc.ascx panel , but could not access any data in it because it always returns null, probably because data is technically in b.ascx and not in abc.ascx. I don't know the reason yet.

So, I ended up taking the long route solution that I had thought before. I had to add a method to the base user control(abstract class) and provide its implementation everywhere required, and override its implementation where I had to.